# Get access to closure dojo object when callback scope was entered

Tags: javascript, websocket, dojo

I have a dojo object, I want to do a retry connection to a web socket. However, the connection to the web socket is triggered by a callback function. I tried subscribing to a `topic` to allow reconnect without using `this`. However, if the class has two or more instance, it gets all the subscribed message on all instance of MyClass. Is there a way to only let the original instance that fail to connect to get the subscribed message?

```
// Dojo class
dojo.declare("MyClass", null, {

    constructor: function() {
        dojo.subscribe("WebSocketConnect", this, function() {
            this.DoConnect();
        });
    }, 

    DoConnect: function() {
        this.myWebSocket = new WebSocket('ws://192.0.0.1');

        // ウェブソケットは閉じたイベント
        this.myWebSocket.onclose = function () {

            // The this in this clousure is "myWebSocket"
            setTimeout(function() {
                dojo.publish("WebSocketConnect", [ ] );
            }, 5000);

        };

    }
}
```

Note: The project I am working on uses dojo 1.4. Quite old but I have no permission to upgrade it.

Comment: Is `MyClass` supposed to be a singleton? If no, then your constructor doesn't work either.

Comment: @Bergi why would the constructor not work? I used the this to indicate the instance? what am I missing?

Comment: For exactly the reason you already stated, *all* instances will receive such a global event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason you dont want to connect to `this`?

When you publish or subscribe, it is dependent on the string id used to identify the "event", If you could make it unique for each instance then you could prevent the function execute on all instance.

```
// Dojo class
dojo.declare("MyClass", null, {

uniqueID:"",

constructor: function() {
    this.uniqueID = <generate unique id>;
    dojo.subscribe("WebSocketConnect" + this.uniqueID, this, function() {
        this.DoConnect();
    });
}, 

DoConnect: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.myWebSocket = new WebSocket('ws://192.0.0.1');

    // ウェブソケットは閉じたイベント
    this.myWebSocket.onclose = function () {

        // The this in this clousure is "myWebSocket"
        setTimeout(function() {
            dojo.publish("WebSocketConnect" + self.uniqueID, [ ] );
        }, 5000);

    };

}
```

}

How you generate the `uniqueID` is upto you, it could be as simple as a global counter or use some logic to create a GUID. Anything will work as long as it is unique.

Comment: `hitch` is better than `self`

Comment: @ben - changing the whole context is not efficient just to get a variable value, hence I used `self`. If we have to execute the mehtod in that context, then it is better to `hitch`.

Comment: Well, it is always the question of efficiency over maintainability. Having a consistant "this" everywhere is a lot more consistent that relying on `this`, `that`, `self`, or random name given by multi developer teams. Yes you loose a little of the efficiency but you gain a lot in maintainability and readability. `this` is consistant and does not give you any "surprise"

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic topic name:

```js
// Dojo class
define(['dijit/registry', 'dojo/_base/declare', 'dojo/topic'], function(registry, declare, topic) {
  declare("MyClass", null, {

      constructor: function() {
        var uniqId = registry.getUniqueId('WebSocketConnect'),
          doConnect = this._DoConnect;

        //for external use
        this.DoConnect = function() {
          doConnect(uniqId);
        }

        //from internal fail
        topic.subscribe("WebSocketConnect" + uniqId, this.DoConnect());



      },

      _DoConnect: function(uniqId) {
        this.myWebSocket = new WebSocket('ws://192.0.0.1');

        // ウェブソケットは閉じたイベント
        this.myWebSocket.onclose = function() {

          // The this in this clousure is "myWebSocket"
          setTimeout(function() {
            topic.publish("WebSocketConnect" + uniqId, []);
          }, 5000);

        };

      }
    }
  });
});
```

but best is to use hitch:

```js
// Dojo class
define(['dojo/_base/declare'], function(declare) {
  declare("MyClass", null, {
      DoConnect: function() {
        this.myWebSocket = new WebSocket('ws://192.0.0.1');

        // ウェブソケットは閉じたイベント
        this.myWebSocket.onclose = lang.hitch(this, function() {
          setTimeout(lang.hitch(this, 'DoConnect'), 5000);
        });

      }
    }
  });
});
```